# Weighted Random Selection with bounded replacement

Tags: random-variable, sample

The problem:
Let there be an array (noted as X) where each item has a member, and a label assigned to it. For example:

$$
X= \{a_0, b_0, b_1, c_0, c_1, a_1\}
$$

Here the letter denotes a label, and the index is just another instance from the given label. Now the goal is to sample n items from X into Y, where:

$$
|Y|=n < m = |X|
$$

and each label has a weight assigned to it, so that in the long run the weights will define the distribution of the elements in Y. Elements from within a label are different, but whichever of them may be selected. The multiplicity of the labels are random too (it may vary from 1 to 10). The length of X will be usually around 100, from which around 10 items need to be selected.

So, let's say if the weights are

$$
W = \{a=5, b=45, c=50\} 
$$
for 10,000 runs if we add up the elements from Y it will be true that 5% of it will be from a, 45% from b, and 50% from c.

The indexes just denote that you have multiple item instances from a label. There is no frequency requirement for within label (so simple random sampling can/should be used).

The sampling is without replacement (considering the full array (X), however it is with bounded replacement if you consider just the labels (that is a,b,c labels).

At the end we do not need exact match with W, expected value is okay. Successive runs may result in slightly different output, that too is okay (although the expected value of the frequency of labels, should approximate W).

Now, I've already tried to do this in python via the roulette wheel selection, where if a label has no more items I redo the roulette, however this sometimes goes really off.

1. What's a good algorithm for this?
2. What's wrong with my code? (why the big difference sometimes - here's the python code http://pastebin.com/SFhV74Z8)

Comment: (1) The role of the indexes in this question is unclear: why are they there?  *E.g.,* for the given values of $X$ and $W$, with what frequencies should $b_0$ and $b_1$ *individually* be chosen? (2) Are you sampling with or without replacement? (3) Must the proportions in the $10,000$ runs be *exactly* the values in $W$ or should the *expectations* of the proportions be the values in $W$? Must successive samples ("runs") be independent or not?

Comment: Updated to answer your questions (see the post).